# Join @ManyToOne hibernate using composite Key

Tags: hibernate

I have this table

[image]

and I have another table which uses only CODE upon type of M_CODE

so this is mapped to 
this two classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PIS_DOMAIN_DETAIL")
public class Domain implements Serializable{

@Id
DomainId id;

@Column(name = "CODE" , insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer code;
@Column(name = "COM_NO")
private Integer comNo;
@Column(name = "DESC_A")
private String descA;
@Column(name = "DESC_L")
private String descL;
@Column(name = "TIMESTAMP")
private Date timestamp;
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private Integer userId;
```

---

and this is embeddable

```
@Embeddable
public class DomainId implements Serializable{
@Column(name = "M_CODE")
private Integer mCode;
@Column(name = "CODE")
private Integer code;}
```

so in Other table that use only code in column WF_STATUS i have created this

```
// this is select id.code from Domain  where id.mCode=35
@Column(name = "WF_STATUS") //that recievce CODE from domain entity
private Integer wfStatus;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "WF_STATUS", referencedColumnName = "CODE",
    insertable = false, updatable = false )
@Where(clause=" id.mCode = 35 ")
Domain status;
```

but this out this error

> More than one row with the given identifier was found: com.project.entities.Domain@50bc3219, for class: com.project.entities.Domain

how i can edit my map to accept this case .. thanks in advance ...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm struggling to follow the details of your problem.  Please present a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, including minimal but complete and fully-annotated example entities and embeddables.

Answer (score 0):

You have a duplicate column, you should decide whether `code` column will be in the `DomainId` as a part of the compound key or not (only in the Domain class).